# Multiple ssl certificates with one ip and same port but different host headers (IIS 8)

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, iis-8, bindings

I have an IIS 8 (win 2012 r2) server and i want to bind the same web site to 2 different domain and to 2 different certificates.

I can't use wildcard since the domains are different FQDNs.

If i add 2 bindings for https and port 443 i can't select 2 different certificates (when i change one binding it changes the other).

There is a way to solve this without using different port or splitting to 2 different websites?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give us more infos what is the reason here? One possible option might be to redirect the one domain to the 2nd one. But that seamed to be to easy in your case ;-)

Comment: There is a simple way in this https://stackoverflow.com/a/27791857/3260008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution - using ssFlags = 1
https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/site/bindings/binding

Answer (score 24):

There is a simple way to do, tick the "Require Server Name Indication" in "Bindings...".

Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27791857/3260008

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: ..and if you have more than one website, you should check that "require server name" in "bindings" (under Https - Edit) also is set for all the OTHER websites you have, or IIS could apply the certificate binded to a website to a different website.